# Discord.py: Unable to send welcome message after moving the welcome message to another module

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to setup a welcome message using Discord.py, and this is what I currently have:

*hydrabot/hydra/settings.py*

```
import discord

# Welcomer settings
welcomeChannel = "819624923445985310"

# Bot intents settings
intents = discord.Intents(members=True)

# Command prefix
command_prefix = '$'

# Bot help page
description = f'''Hydra Commands
Hydra's command prefix is "{command_prefix}"
'''
```

*hydrabot/hydra/main.py*

```
import os

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from settings import(
    intents,
    command_prefix,
    description)
from welcome_message import welcomeMessage

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=command_prefix, description=description, intents=intents)
@bot.event

async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member.name} has joined the server. Attempting to send welcome message...")
    await member.send(welcomeMessage)
    print(f'Sent welcome message to {member.name}.')
```

*hydrabot/hydra/welcome_message.py*

```
import discord

welcomeMessage = f'Welcome to the server, {member.mention}!'
```

Whenever I run the program, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\liljo\OneDrive\Projects\hydrabot\hydra\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from welcome_message import welcomeMessage
  File "C:\Users\liljo\OneDrive\Projects\hydrabot\hydra\welcome_message.py", line 3, in <module>
    welcomeMessage = f'Welcome to the server, {member.mention}!'
NameError: name 'member' is not defined
```

Wasn't `member` defined when I imported `discord`? Here is what happens if I use `from discord import member` instead of `import discord`:
*hydrabot/hydra/welcome_message.py*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\liljo\OneDrive\Projects\hydrabot\hydra\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from welcome_message import welcomeMessage
  File "C:\Users\liljo\OneDrive\Projects\hydrabot\hydra\welcome_message.py", line 3, in <module>
    welcomeMessage = f'Welcome to the server, {member.mention}!'
AttributeError: module 'discord.member' has no attribute 'mention'
```

How is there not an attribute named `mention`, but the program runs fine whenever I move the welcome message back to `main.py`?

Comment: The errors speaks for itself, `member` is not defined. You can try to use something like `member = discord.Member`

Comment: You don't have the least amount of knowledge necessary to start with discord.py. Learn more OOP, and more programming in general, it's going to be a lot easier for you. discord.py is **NOT** a library for beginners

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the `member` variable from `main.py` to `welcome_message.py`.

1. Solution: You can just directly define the welcome message in main.py, it isn't worth it to define it in another file
2. Solution: You can put the welcome message in welcome_message.py in a function where you pass the parameter `member`

welcome_message.py:

```
def welcomemessage(member):
    ...
    return welcomeMessage
```

main.py:

```
import welcome_message
welcome_message.welcomemessage(member)
```